# How to navigate to specific screen upon receiving notification in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, navigation, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am receiving two kinds of notifications on my flutter application with firebase as backend successfully, implemented `FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK` in the cloud function to provide the on tap functionality,

Now I want is that as there are two kind of different notifications and I want the navigation of the specific screen according to the notification value. How should I do that?

Below is the code I am using `data payloads` and `flutter code`

**PAYLOAD 1**

```
const payload = {

              notification : {
                  title: item title,
                  body: notificaionmessage,
                  icon:"default"
                              },

                              data: {
                                       click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                                       notification_id: notification_id,
                                       //senderAvatarURL: messageRecieverSenderAvatar,
                                       category: 'default'
                                     }
          };
```

**PAYLOAD 2**

```
const payload = {
                    notification: {
                      title: `NOTIFICATION2 `,
                      body: contentMessage,
                      badge: '1',
                      sound: 'default'
                    },
                    data: {
                             click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                             notification2: notificationid2,
                             //senderAvatarURL: messageRecieverSenderAvatar,
                             category: 'default'
                           }
                  }
```

**CODE TO HANDLE THE NOTIFICATION**

```
firebaseMessaging.configure(onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onMessage: $message');
      Platform.isAndroid ? showNotification(message['notification']) : showNotification(message['aps']['alert']);
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> SCREEN1()));
      return;
    }, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onResume: $message');
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> SCREEN1()));
      return;
    }, onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onLaunch: $message');
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> SCREEN1()));
      return;
    });
```

As in the above the navigation is configured but I want it to be to the different screens according to the payload, for instance `PAYLOAD 1 to SCREEN1` and `PAYLOAD 2 to SCREEN 2`

How should I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways.

for example you can check the

click_action: 'Move_To_Screen1'

```
if (message['data']['click_action']=='Move_To_Screen1') 
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> SCREEN1()));
else if (message['data']['click_action']=='Move_To_Screen2') 
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> SCREEN2()));
```

Hope that helps .